# Can I set up a bindingRedirect to a wildcard version?

Tags: .net, .net-assembly, versioning

I have to update my bindingRedirects whenever I use a new version of a library, I've used Newtonsoft.Json in the example because it's a very popular dependency.

For example:

```
 <dependentAssembly>
     <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
         <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.0.0" newVersion="8.0.0.0" />
 </dependentAssembly>
```

Is it possible to say I want the highest version available so long at it is higher than a version?